# INSERT INTO with variable for DB

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, insert-into

I want to insert:

- to database `TEST`, table `SUBJECT`, field `aSubject` when `@Database = 'TS'`
- to database `TEST1`, table `SUBJECT`, field `aSubject` when `@Database = 'TS1'`
- else to database `DEMO`, table `SUBJECT`, field `aSubject`

I tried this:

```
DECLARE @Database varchar(10)
Set @Database = 'TS'

INSERT INTO
(
CASE
WHEN @Database = 'TS' THEN 'TEST.dbo.SUBJECT' 
WHEN @Database = 'TS1' then 'TEST1.dbo.SUBJECT'
ELSE 'DEMO.dbo.SUBJECT' END
) (aSubject)
SELECT 'Company'
```

I get error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near '('.
```

Comment: A table or column name cannot be a variable.  In effect you have to create a new SQL statement that expands the variables.  One way to do that is dynamic SQL, like `declare @sql varchar(max) = 'select ...'; exec @sql;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Database SYSNAME;
Set @Database = 'TS'

SET @Database = CASE
                    WHEN @Database = 'TS'  THEN 'TEST' 
                    WHEN @Database = 'TS1' THEN 'TEST1'
                    ELSE 'DEMO' 
                END


DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);


SET @sql= N' INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@Database) + N'.[dbo].[SUBJECT] '
        + N' SELECT ''Company'' '

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```